# Locationmanager startmonitoringforregion not calling delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to make a region based reminder. I have a viewcontroller that pops up when I need to add the reminder. In that vc I select a region where I need to be reminded and then use startMonitoringForRegion method. I set the locationManager delegate to the AppDelegate so that the AppDelegate can respond to entering or exiting the region.
The problem is that the when I close the viewcontroller the delegate methods don't get called. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:
AddReminderVC

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:self.lastCenter radius:self.radius identifier:@"id"];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

AppDelegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"EXIT REGION");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"ENTER REGION");
}
```

Note that the methods do get called when the AddReminderVC is still visible. Only when it gets dismissed the delegate methods don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to instantiate the locationManager in your AppDelegate or write another Singleton class to hold the locationManager. If you set it in a viewController the arc will delete the object when there are no more references to it.